How would I prove the sequent $p \vee q, q \vee r, p \rightarrow \neg r \vdash q$ using natural deduction rules?
I'm stuck on this logic problem that I'm unable to prove using natural deduction rules. I thought since we have both a $r$ and negated $r$, and (*) $(q \vee r)$, we could show that if we've a $\neg r$, we would necessarily have $(q \vee (\text{something false}))$ from (*), which necessitates that q is true? Would this be a strategy that could work? I am still rusty with natural deduction since it has a formalistic approach.
Here's the sequent: $$p \vee q, q \vee r, p \rightarrow \neg r \vdash q$$
Natural deduction rules for propositional logic

About your "$(*)(q\lor r)$" and "if we've a $\neg r$" then "$q$ is true", this may be known as disjunctive syllogism.

Your rules are for introduction and elimination of various connectives.
Your premises are two disjunctions and a conditional statement, the later which also contains a negation.
Your conclusion is an atomic predicate (ie: has no connective).
Therefore, you will mainly want to use the elimination rules for disjunctions, conditional, and negation.
Look closely at $\vee$e , $\to$e , and $\neg$e .   In particular, notice that the later produces an unrequired $\bot$, however, the $\bot$ elimination rule produces anything you might require.
So, the relevant pieces of the puzzle are:
$\quad$ $~\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{p\vee q}~~\dfrac{\boxed{p\\\vdots}}{q}~~\dfrac{q}{q}}{q}{\small\vee e}~$, $~\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{q\vee r}~~\dfrac{q}{q}~~\dfrac{\boxed{r\\\vdots}}{q}}{q}{\small\vee e}~$, $~\dfrac{p~~~p\to\neg r}{\neg r}{\small{\to}e}~$, $\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}r~~~\dfrac{\boxed{\vdots}}{\neg r}}{\bot}{\small\neg e}~$, and $~\dfrac{\bot}{q}{\small\bot e}~$ .
Just put them together.
To start you off$$\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{p\vee q}~~\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{q\vee r}~~\dfrac{q}{q}~~\dfrac{\boxed{p\quad r\quad p\to\neg r\\\hspace{6ex}\vdots}}{q}}{q}{\small\vee e}~~\dfrac{q}{q}}{q}{\small\vee e}$$
